# Generalize class method that does slightly different actions according to condition

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

I have a simplified class `Animal` that can do `food_routine` in which the actions differ depending on the type of the animal:

```
DOG = 'dog'
CAT = 'cat'

class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, animal_type):
        if animal_type not in [CAT, DOG]:
            raise Exception('unexpected animal')
        self.animal_type = animal_type

    def food_routine(self):
        self.come_to_plate()  # common code
        self.sniff_food()  # common code

        if self.animal_type == CAT:
            self.go_around_plate()

        self.eat_the_food()  # common code

        if self.animal_type == DOG:  # condition I want to avoid
            self.thank_owner()

        self.go_away_from_plate()  # common code

        # cats and dogs do different things after eating:
        if self.animal_type == CAT:  # condition I want to avoid
            self.go_lie_on_couch()
        elif self.animal_type == DOG:  # condition I want to avoid
            self.ask_for_walk_outside()

        self.sleep()  # common code

    def sleep(self):
        print 'sleep'  # common code

    def ask_for_walk_outside(self):
        print 'ask for a walk outside'

    def go_lie_on_couch(self):
        print 'go lie on couch'

    def go_away_from_plate(self):
        print 'go away from plate'  # common code

    def thank_owner(self):
        print 'thank owner'  # only dogs thank owner

    def eat_the_food(self):
        print 'eat the food'  # common code

    def go_around_plate(self):
        print 'go around plate'

    def sniff_food(self):
        print 'sniff food'  # common code

    def come_to_plate(self):
        print 'come to plate'  # common code
```

My problem is the `if` statements that make the code unreadable. I tried to solve it by creating two classes: one for Dog and one for Cat. Each animal only does things he knows to do in `food_routine` (and removed the method from `Animal`):

```
class Cat(Animal):
    def food_routine(self):
        self.come_to_plate()  # common code
        self.sniff_food()  # common code
        self.go_around_plate()
        self.eat_the_food()  # common code
        self.go_away_from_plate()  # common code
        self.go_lie_on_couch()
        self.sleep()  # common code


class Dog(Animal):
    def food_routine(self):
        self.come_to_plate()  # common code
        self.sniff_food()  # common code
        self.eat_the_food()  # common code
        self.thank_owner()
        self.go_away_from_plate()  # common code
        self.ask_for_walk_outside()
        self.sleep()  # common code
```

This results in code duplication (`common code` lines) which I want to avoid.

So my question is: What is a good practice to avoid code duplication but also to avoid the `if` statements so the code is readable and simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The food_routine should be mutual.

Divide your actions into phases - "pre action", "action", "post action".
Each class should implement the "pre action" functions and "post action" functions, and the Animal class should contain all the common code.
Each dog/cat should call the super "pre" and "post" in order to avoid code duplication.

```
class Animal(object):
    .
    .
    .
    def action():
        self.eat_the_food()  # common code

    def pre_action():
        self.come_to_plate()  # common code
        self.sniff_food()  # common code

    def post_action():
        self.go_away_from_plate()  # common code
        self.sleep()  # common code


class Cat(Animal):
    .
    .
    def pre_action():
        super().pre_action()
        self.go_around_plate()


class Dog(Animal)
    .
    .
    .
    def post_action():
        self.thank_owner()
        self.ask_for_walk_outside()
        self.super().post_action()
```

And then, each call can be:

```
Dog.pre_action()
Dog.action()
Dog.post_action()
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def food_routine(self):
    self.come_to_plate()  # common code
    self.sniff_food()  # common code

    self._pre_eat_action()

    self.eat_the_food()  # common code

    self._post_eat_action()

    self.go_away_from_plate()  # common code

    self._post_leave_plate_action()

    self.sleep()  # common code
```

Then implement `_pre_eat_action`, `_post_eat_action`, and `_post_leave_plate_action` in both `Dog` and `Cat` to handle the two different behaviors.